# How do you a change guild icon from a list of randomly selected local image's?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, typeerror, nextcord

I have been trying to make a Slash command to change the Guild's icon. The icon it changes it to is picked from a list of icons at random but I'm getting this error and have no idea what it means:

```
Ignoring exception in command icon_change: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\application_command.py", line 1053, in _call_with_hooks
    await callback(*args)   File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\application_command.py", line 1135, in call_invoke_slash
    await self.invoke_slash(interaction, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\application_command.py", line 1228, in invoke_slash
    await self.callback(interaction, **kwargs)   File "C:\PC Code\Python\Nextcord - Bots\utilities 2.6 - NextCord.py", line 255, in icon_change
    await interaction.guild.edit(icon=ficon)   File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\guild.py", line 1570, in edit
    fields['icon'] = utils._bytes_to_base64_data(icon)   File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\utils.py", line 495, in _bytes_to_base64_data
    mime = _get_mime_type_for_image(data)   File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\utils.py", line 481, in _get_mime_type_for_image
    if data.startswith(b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A'): TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
@bot.slash_command(description="Change server icon")
@application_checks.is_owner()
async def icon_change(interaction : Interaction):
    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logoaa.png', 'rb') as Iconaa:
        icona = Iconaa.read()

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logocc.png', 'rb') as Iconcc:
        iconc = Iconcc.read()

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logodd.png', 'rb') as Icondd:
        icond = Icondd.read()

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logoff.png', 'rb') as Iconff:
        iconf = Iconff.read()

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logohh.png', 'rb') as Iconhh:
        iconh = Iconhh.read()

        iconch = ['icona', 'iconc', 'icond', 'iconf', 'iconh']
        ficon = random.choice(iconch)
    await interaction.guild.edit(icon=ficon)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by converting the image to a byte array using '**bytearray()**'

Example:

```
with open('C:\Images\Image.png', 'rb') as Image:
     a = Image.read()
     imageA = bytearray(a)
```

Fixed code:

```
@bot.slash_command(description="Change server icon")
@application_checks.is_owner()
async def icon_change(interaction : Interaction):
    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logoaa.png', 'rb') as Iconaa:
        iconaaa = Iconaa.read()
        icona = bytearray(iconaaa)

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logocc.png', 'rb') as Iconcc:
        iconccc = Iconcc.read()
        iconc = bytearray(iconccc)

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logodd.png', 'rb') as Icondd:
        iconddd = Icondd.read()
        icond = bytearray(iconddd)

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logoff.png', 'rb') as Iconff:
        iconfff = Iconff.read()
        iconf = bytearray(iconfff)

    with open('C:\Server_Icons\Logohh.png', 'rb') as Iconhh:
        iconhhh = Iconhh.read()
        iconh = bytearray(iconhhh)

    iconch = [icona, iconc, icond, iconf, iconh]
    ficon = random.choice(iconch)
    await interaction.send(f"Icon changed!")
    await interaction.guild.edit(icon=ficon)
```